# Unable to navigate to salesforce page from Aura application (lightning:navigation)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning, aura, lightningnavigation

I've created an aura component to display Contacts list in the form of a data table, When I click on the contact Name I was unable to navigate to salesforce page for that particular contact.

```
<aura:component controller ="taskThree"
              implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="url" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="pageReference" type="Object"/>
    
    <aura:attribute name="Contacts" type ="Contact"/>
      
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchcont}"/>
   
    
    <lightning:datatable data="{!v.Contacts}"
                         columns="{!v.mycolumns}"
                         keyField="Id"
                         hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                         onrowaction="{!c.handleRowAction}">>
        
        </lightning:datatable>
    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
    <a href="{!v.url}">Link</a>
        
    
</aura:component>
```

**Aura Controller JS:**

```
({
    fetchcont : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.mycolumns', 
   [{label: 'Contact Id', fieldName: 'Id', type:'String'},
    {label: 'Contact Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'url',typeAttributes:{label: { fieldName: 'Name' }, target: '_blank'}},
    {label: 'Account Name', fieldName:'AccountId',type:'text'},
    {label: 'Contact Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone'},
    {label:'view', type:'button', initialWidth:135, 
     typeAttributes:
                {label:'view Details', name:'view_details',title:'click to view Details'}}
    
            ]);
        var action = component.get("c.fetchContacts");
       
       
        action.setParams({
            ContactId: component.get("v.recordId")
 
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
       component.set("v.Contacts", response.getReturnValue());
     
    })
        
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
   
    
    handleRowAction: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var action = event.getParam("action");
    var row = event.getParam("row");
        if (action.name === "view_details") {
            alert("Contact Name: " + row.Name + "\nAccount Name: " + row.AccountId + "\nPhone: " + row.Phone);
        }else{
        alert("error...");
        }
     var navService = cmp.find("navService");
        // Sets the route to /lightning/o/Account/home
        var pageReference = {
    "type": "standard__recordPage",
    "attributes": {
        "recordId": ContactId,
        "actionName": actionName? actionName: "view"
            }
        };
        
       cmp.set("v.pageReference", pageReference);
        
        var defaultUrl = https://xxxxxx-dev-ed.develop.lightning.force.com/lightning/Contact/'+Id+'/view";
        navService.generateUrl(pageReference)
            .then($A.getCallback(function(url) {
                cmp.set("v.url", url ? url : defaultUrl);
            }), $A.getCallback(function(error) {
                cmp.set("v.url", defaultUrl);
            }));
}
        })
```

**Apex class:**

```
public class taskThree{
    @AuraEnabled
       public static List <Contact> fetchContacts(Id recordId){
       List<Contact> contList = [Select ID,name,AccountId,Phone from Contact];
       
       return contList;
      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create url for the Object page but you want to navigate to a standard record page.

```
var navService = cmp.find("navService");
var pageReference = {
        "type": "standard__recordPage",
        "attributes": {
            "recordId": component.get("v.recordId"),
            "actionName": actionName? actionName: "view"   //clone, edit, view
        }
    };
navService.navigate(pageReference); // to directly navigate
```

You can read more at - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation

Comment: Hello Mukul Mahawariya,
his page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Error in $A.getCallback() [recordId is not defined]
Callback failed: apex://shadowThree/ACTION$fetchContacts...
i am getting this error..

Comment: Well you need to pass the contact Idi] in place recordId

Comment: Hey @Mukul Mahawariya, I tried with contact Id ..I am getting the same error

Comment: @Capcena, share the updated code

Comment: Hey @Mukul Mahawariya , I edited the code...Please try with your salesforce url and let me know if it is working or not..

Comment: You are adding contactId as it is not defined, you have to give the contact Id which is stored in the recordId attribute. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I edited the code but it is not navigating to the contact page...did it navigated for you on clicking a particular contact?

Comment: and yeah we did the set params...right at ...
action.setParams({
            ContactId: component.get("v.recordId").....so again no need to define right? .....

Comment: No you are getting it wrong, have you tried replacing the contacted with component.get("v.recordId").

Comment: Yeah I tried...Navigation part is not working..

Comment: can u tell me how to dynamically pass the url in aura JS part...

Comment: As of now there is no error ....only the navigation part is not working..

Comment: @Capcena, try logging the url before setting in v.url whether it's generating any URL or not